# understanding the routes module with view and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created controller profiles with a method testimonials and index, then I created its view in `app/views/profiles/testimonials.html.erb`

In `routes.rb` file I have

```
get 'profiles/testimonials', to: 'profiles#testimonials
```

then I have created a link to this view like this

```
<%= link_to "Testimonials", :controller => "profiles", :action => "testimonials" %>
```

I can see from running the rake routes command the following route

```
profiles_testimonials GET    /profiles/testimonials(.:format) profiles#testimonials
```

still when I click the link in my browser I get the error

```
The action 'show' could not be found for ProfilesController
```

I don't understand from where does the method `show` comes in the picture, I don't want to create a `show` method all.

Comment: Have you try to use more resource oriented rails syntax, like this:            <%= link_to "Testimonials", profiles_testimonials_path() %>

Comment: I tried this but still it gives me the same error

Comment: I got my problem solved by removing resources :profiles which was force fully looking for show method